# Why does Cassandra major compaction fail to clear expired tombstones?

Tags: cassandra, tombstone

We have deployed a global Apache Cassandra cluster (node: 12, RF: 3, version: 3.11.2) in our production environment. We are running into an issue where running major compaction on column family is failing to clear tombstones from one node (out of 3 replicas) even though metadata information shows min timestamp passed gc_grace_seconds set on the table.

Here is sstable metadata output

```
SSTable: mc-4302-big
Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
Bloom Filter FP chance: 0.010000
Minimum timestamp: 1
Maximum timestamp: 1560326019515476
SSTable min local deletion time: 1560233203
SSTable max local deletion time: 2147483647
Compressor: org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor
Compression ratio: 0.8808303792058351
TTL min: 0
TTL max: 0
First token: -9201661616334346390 (key=bca773eb-ecbb-49ec-9330-cc16da310b58:::)
Last token: 9117719078924671254 (key=7c23b975-5354-4c82-82e5-1762bac75a8d:::)
minClustringValues: [00000f8f-74a9-4ce3-9d87-0a4dabef30c1]
maxClustringValues: [ffffc966-a02c-4e1f-bdd1-256556624288]
Estimated droppable tombstones: 46.31761624099541
SSTable Level: 0
Repaired at: 0
Replay positions covered: {}
totalColumnsSet: 0
totalRows: 618382
Estimated tombstone drop times:
1560233680:       353
1560234658:       237
1560235604:       176
1560236803:       471
1560237652:       402
1560238342:       195
1560239166:       373
1560239969:       356
1560240586:       262
1560241207:       247
1560242037:       387
1560242847:       357
1560243742:       280
1560244469:       283
1560245095:       353
1560245957:       357
1560246773:       362
1560247956:       449
1560249034:       217
1560249849:       310
1560251080:       296
1560251984:       304
1560252993:       239
1560253907:       407
1560254839:       977
1560255761:       671
1560256486:       317
1560257199:       679
1560258020:       703
1560258795:       507
1560259378:       298
1560260093:      2302
1560260869:      2488
1560261535:      2818
1560262176:      2842
1560262981:      1685
1560263708:      1830
1560264308:       808
1560264941:      1990
1560265753:      1340
1560266708:      2174
1560267629:      2253
1560268400:      1627
1560269174:      2347
1560270019:      2579
1560270888:      3947
1560271690:      1727
1560272446:      2573
1560273249:      1523
1560274086:      3438
1560275149:      2737
1560275966:      3487
1560276814:      4101
1560277660:      2012
1560278617:      1198
1560279680:       769
1560280441:      1337
1560281033:       608
1560281876:      2065
1560282546:      2926
1560283128:      6305
1560283836:       824
1560284574:        71
1560285166:       140
1560285828:       118
1560286404:        83
1560295835:        72
1560296951:       456
1560297814:       670
1560298496:       271
1560299333:       473
1560300159:       284
1560300831:       127
1560301551:       536
1560302309:       425
1560303302:       860
1560304064:       465
1560304782:       319
1560305657:       323
1560306552:       236
1560307454:       368
1560308409:       320
1560309178:       210
1560310091:       177
1560310881:        85
1560311970:       147
1560312706:        76
1560313495:        88
1560314847:       687
1560315817:      1618
1560316544:      1245
1560317423:      5361
1560318491:      2060
1560319595:      5853
1560320587:      5390
1560321473:      3868
1560322644:      5784
1560323703:      6861
1560324838:      7200
1560325744:      5642
Count               Row Size        Cell Count
1                          0              3054
2                          0                 0
3                          0                 0
4                          0                 0
5                          0                 0
6                          0                 0
7                          0                 0
8                          0                 0
10                         0                 0
12                         0                 0
14                         0                 0
17                         0                 0
20                         0                 0
24                         0                 0
29                         0                 0
35                         0                 0
42                         0                 0
50                         0                 0
60                        98                 0
72                        49                 0
86                        46                 0
103                     2374                 0
124                       39                 0
149                       36                 0
179                       43                 0
215                       18                 0
258                       26                 0
310                       24                 0
372                       18                 0
446                       16                 0
535                       19                 0
642                       27                 0
770                       17                 0
924                       12                 0
1109                      14                 0
1331                      23                 0
1597                      20                 0
1916                      12                 0
2299                      11                 0
2759                      11                 0
3311                      11                 0
3973                      12                 0
4768                       5                 0
5722                       8                 0
6866                       5                 0
8239                       5                 0
9887                       6                 0
11864                      5                 0
14237                     10                 0
17084                      1                 0
20501                      8                 0
24601                      2                 0
29521                      2                 0
35425                      3                 0
42510                      2                 0
51012                      2                 0
61214                      1                 0
73457                      2                 0
88148                      3                 0
105778                     0                 0
126934                     3                 0
152321                     2                 0
182785                     1                 0
219342                     0                 0
263210                     0                 0
315852                     0                 0
379022                     0                 0
454826                     0                 0
545791                     0                 0
654949                     0                 0
785939                     0                 0
943127                     0                 0
1131752                    0                 0
1358102                    0                 0
1629722                    0                 0
1955666                    0                 0
2346799                    0                 0
2816159                    0                 0
3379391                    1                 0
4055269                    0                 0
4866323                    0                 0
5839588                    0                 0
7007506                    0                 0
8409007                    0                 0
10090808                   1                 0
12108970                   0                 0
14530764                   0                 0
17436917                   0                 0
20924300                   0                 0
25109160                   0                 0
30130992                   0                 0
36157190                   0                 0
43388628                   0                 0
52066354                   0                 0
62479625                   0                 0
74975550                   0                 0
89970660                   0                 0
107964792                  0                 0
129557750                  0                 0
155469300                  0                 0
186563160                  0                 0
223875792                  0                 0
268650950                  0                 0
322381140                  0                 0
386857368                  0                 0
464228842                  0                 0
557074610                  0                 0
668489532                  0                 0
802187438                  0                 0
962624926                  0                 0
1155149911                 0                 0
1386179893                 0                 0
1663415872                 0                 0
1996099046                 0                 0
2395318855                 0                 0
2874382626                 0                  
3449259151                 0                  
4139110981                 0                  
4966933177                 0                  
5960319812                 0                  
7152383774                 0                  
8582860529                 0                  
10299432635                 0                  
12359319162                 0                  
14831182994                 0                  
17797419593                 0                  
21356903512                 0                  
25628284214                 0                  
30753941057                 0                  
36904729268                 0                  
44285675122                 0                  
53142810146                 0                  
63771372175                 0                  
76525646610                 0                  
91830775932                 0                  
110196931118                 0                  
132236317342                 0                  
158683580810                 0                  
190420296972                 0                  
228504356366                 0                  
274205227639                 0                  
329046273167                 0                  
394855527800                 0                  
473826633360                 0                  
568591960032                 0                  
682310352038                 0                  
818772422446                 0                  
982526906935                 0                  
1179032288322                 0                  
1414838745986                 0                  
Estimated cardinality: 3054
EncodingStats minTTL: 0
EncodingStats minLocalDeletionTime: 1560233203
EncodingStats minTimestamp: 1
KeyType: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.CompositeType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type)
ClusteringTypes: [org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UUIDType]
StaticColumns: {}
RegularColumns: {}
```

So far here is what we have tried,
1) major compaction with lower gc_grace_seconds
2) nodetool garbagecollect
3) nodetool scrub

None of the above methods is helping. Again, this is only happening for one node (out of total 3 replicas)

Answer (score 2):

The tombstone markers generated during your major compaction are just that, markers.  The data has been removed but a delete marker is left in place so that the other replicas can have gc_grace_seconds to process them too.  The tombstone markers are fully dropped the next time the SSTable is compacted.  Unfortunately because you've run a major compaction (rarely ever recommended) it may be a long time until there are suitable SSTables for compaction with it to clean up the tombstones.  Remember that the tombstone drop will also only happen after local_delete_time + gc_grace_seconds as defined by the table.

If you're interested in learning more about how tombstones and compaction work together in the context of delete operations I suggest reading the following articles:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlAboutDeletes.html
https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/07/27/about-deletes-and-tombstones.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In our case, gc_grace is set to one day, and data I am referring to was one month old (> local_delete_time + gc_grace_seconds). Due to our data pattern, we run major compaction every day to evict tombstones. Also, in our case for some reason tombstones were stuck only on one node. Other nodes correctly evicted tombstones post major compaction.